# Emulating flipbook-vue, but without Javascript and images

Tags: css

I'm trying to emulate [flipbook-vue](https://ts1.github.io/flipbook-vue/) component, but with pure CSS.

I would like to combine that component with [this CSS example](https://codepen.io/dhanishgajjar/pen/bjaYYo) on CodePen.

On the flipbook-vue side, I like how the book remains centered when the first page opens, is that possible to do with CSS only? I tried, but the book doesn't expand as the cover rotates.

Also, do the pages need to go backwards like on CodePen example?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test page flip</title>
        
        <style>
        
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            
            body {
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                overflow: hidden;
                text-align: center;
            }
        
            div {
                height: 100%;
            }
            
            #book {
                border: 1px solid blue;
                display: inline-block;
                background: #eee;
                text-align: center;
            }
            
            div.page {
                border: 1px solid red;
                width: 40vw;
                height: 60%;
            }
            
            div.page.flipped {
                transition: transform 1s;
                transform: rotateY(180deg);
                transform-origin: left center;
            }
        
        </style>
        
        <script>
        
            window.onload = () => {
                setTimeout(flipPage, 1000);
            }
            
            flipPage = () => {
                document.getElementById('page-1').classList.add('flipped');
            }
            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="book">
            <div class="page" id="page-1">
                PAGE 1
            </div>
            <div class="page" id="page-2">
                PAGE 2
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'm happy enough with the solution I came up with

```js
var page = 1;
var timerId = null;

window.onload = () => {
    timerId = setInterval(flipPage, 1000);
}

toggleClass = (id, cssClass) => {
    document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle(cssClass);
}

flipPage = () => {
    if (page === 1) {
        toggleClass('book', 'two-pages');
    } else if (page === 8) {
        toggleClass('book', 'closed');
        toggleClass('book', 'two-pages');
        clearInterval(timerId);
    }
    
    toggleClass('page-' + page, 'flipped');
    page ++;
    
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    --page-width: 40vw;
    --transition-speed: 2s;
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    perspective: 400vw;
    background: #ccc;
}

body, .page > div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#book, .page {
    width: var(--page-width);
    height: 80vh;
}

#book {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    backface-visibility: visible;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    transition: var(--transition-speed) all ease;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#book.two-pages {
    width: calc(2 * var(--page-width));
}

#book.closed {
    width: calc(3 * var(--page-width));
}

.front, .back {
    background: navy;
}

.page {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

div.page.flipped {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transition: transform var(--transition-speed);
    transform-origin: left center;
}

.page > div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.page > div.back-face {
    opacity: 0;
}

.page.flipped > div.front-face {
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-delay: calc(0.3 * var(--transition-speed));
    opacity: 0;
}

.page.flipped > div.back-face {
    opacity: 0;
}

.page.flipped > div.back-face {
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-delay: calc(0.3 * var(--transition-speed));
    opacity: 1;
}

#page-1.flipped {
    transform: rotateY(-180.04deg);
}

#page-2.flipped {
    transform: rotateY(-180.03deg);
}

#page-3.flipped {
    transform: rotateY(-180.02deg);
}

#page-4.flipped {
    transform: rotateY(-180.01deg);
}

#page-5.flipped {
    transform: rotateY(-180.0deg);
}

#page-6.flipped {
    transform: rotateY(-179.99deg);
}

#page-7.flipped {
    transform: rotateY(-179.98deg);
}

#page-8.flipped {
    transform: rotateY(-179.97deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="book" class="book">
  <div class="page back" id="page-8">
    <div class="front-face">PAGE 8</div>
    <div class="back-face">BYE</div>
  </div>

  <div class="page page6" id="page-7">
    <div class="front-face">PAGE 7</div>
    <div class="back-face"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="page page5" id="page-6">
    <div class="front-face">PAGE 6</div>
    <div class="back-face"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="page page4" id="page-5">
    <div class="front-face">PAGE 5</div>
    <div class="back-face"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="page page3" id="page-4">
    <div class="front-face">PAGE 4</div>
    <div class="back-face"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="page page2" id="page-3">
    <div class="front-face">PAGE 3</div>
    <div class="back-face"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="page page1" id="page-2">
    <div class="front-face">PAGE 2</div>
    <div class="back-face"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="page front" id="page-1">
    <div class="front-face">HELLO</div>
    <div class="back-face">TO</div>
  </div>

</div>
```